# Case insensitive LIKE in DB2

Tags: db2, like, string-searching

Is there a way to do a `LIKE` operation in DB2 against a varchar column in a case insensitive way, without changing the underlying column definition?

Or is there a workaround like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE '%string%' OR mycolumn LIKE '%STRING%'` that would work?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565566/query-db2-using-collation

Comment: what platform and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Assuming Db2 for LUW, you can choose a case-insensitive collating table, but only at the database creation time.

You'll have to standardise the case for comparison, with obvious performance implications:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LCASE(mycolumn) LIKE '%string%'
```

Comment: on Db2 for i at least, you can set your session to use a different collation...

Comment: @Charles Do you have a link that explains how to do that, set session collation? My google skills are failing me on this.

Comment: @amber you should ask this as a new question

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(mycolumn,'string',1,'i')
```

Will work if your Db2 version supports regular expression functions 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061494.html
and if you escape any regex meta-characters in your string